# process.env.NODE_ENV is development in after heroku development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

Deployed React app to Heroku.

I set local variable `NODE_ENV` to production but

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

return `'development'`
[image]

Tried in CLI:

```
heroku config:get NODE_ENV -a mydynasty
```

and it returns `'production'`

What am I missing?

Comment: First set: `heroku config:set NODE_ENV -a mydynasty`,
Then get: `heroku config:get NODE_ENV`

Comment: Already tried, it returns production, but console.log(process.env) returns {NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: ""}

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with buildpack, used nodejs buildpack instead of https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack